# Do you have any idea on how to implement efax using SMTP Mail Driver (MAILGUN)

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4, mailgun

[This is the sample email I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ17l.png)

This is my code:

Laravel 4.2

Controller:

```
Mail::send('emails.patient.fax-note'){
    $message->to('61756041159@efaxsend.com');
    $message->to('sunnycris1229@gmail.com', "Sunny");
    $message->subject('Test Fax Notes Using smtp.mailgun.org');
    $message->from('support@lktconsult.com');
} , "-f support@lktconsult.com");
```

mail.php setting

```
'driver' => 'mailgun',
'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => "support@lktconsult.com", 'name' => "Hippocamp"),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => "support@lktconsult.com",
'password' => "mypassword",
```

services.php

```
'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => 'sandbox9a694deec43645249032794f0b054c82.mailgun.org',
    'secret' => 'my key here',
),
```

My Code works perfectly in the email, but not in efax, because efax only accept the mail if you send it to :61756041159@efaxsend.com  and most importantly from: support@lktconsult.com  , My problem is,  the image I attached is the original email I received in my gmail.. stating that it came from : Received: from mail1.static.mgsend.net (mail1.static.mgsend.net. [104.130.122.1])  thats why efax does not accept the email.